Proving a version of law of large numbers.
Suppose that we flip a fair coin and record a 0 whenever heads appears and a 1 whenever tails appears. Note that each sequence of coin flips gives us an element of $X.$
Given a sequence $\textbf{x} = (a_1, a_2,a_3, \dots , a_n, \dots),$ let $$A_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$$ be the average of all numbers we have recorded from flip $1$ to flip $n.$ I want to show that $A_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ almost surely.
Some thoughts:
Under the assumptions that $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ i.e., the probability space of sequences $x = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ where each $a_i$ is either $0$ or $1.$  And $T:X \to X$ is the backward shift operator which is known to be ergodic and $\mu$-invariant. I think I can also use the Birkhoff's ergodic theorem where our function $f$ is the indicator function supported at something that I do not know, can you help me with this please? I am guessing that it is the interval $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$ but I am not sure. I am also guessing that we will have a geometric series that will converge to half but I am not sure how the $n$ in the denominator of $A_n$ will be cancelled and how the limit operation in Birkhoff's will appear in this context.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Your sequece satisfies the conditions of the strong LLN for which you can find standard proofs.

@KurtG. I do not know this property so I have to start the proof from scratch

We cannot pretend that we don't know a proof that is easy to find in evary probability text book. Some expectations on MSE to get it delivered on a silver plate are outrageous.

ok, sorry about that I just thought that there might be a direct way of the proof without using any theorem @KurtG that is what I meant to say.

In that case it is confusing that you mentioned an ergodic theorem in OP.

No I meant to say that @KurtG. So maybe you want to tell me that there is no other way of the proof than using the theorem you mentioned. Am I right?

I did not say that. Read the link I provided which says "The strong law of large numbers can itself be seen as a special case of the pointwise ergodic theorem." Have a nice day.

It's true that the strong law of large numbers can be proved from Birkhoff's pointwise ergodic theorem. I believe the correct choice of $f$ would be $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\mapsto a_1$, as this would result in your desired sum (which converges a.e. to the expectation by Birkhoff's).
Here is a reference for the proof of SLLN using Birkhoff's (you can see that their $\varphi$ is our $f$, and their $f$ is our $T$).

sorry if this is a stupid question but where exactly the proof in the document?

Page 4 outlines how the strong law of large numbers can be proven using Birkhoff's ergodic theorem. The notation looks a bit different than the traditional statement of SLLN, but if you unpack everything, they are equivalent.

thank you very much for your help
